# Isn't having both assumptions that $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ have solutions $\forall a,b \in G$ redundant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the book of *Algebra* by Hungerford, at page 25, it is given that

[image]

However, in the proposition 1.4, the one of the conditions that $ax =b$ and $ya=b$ have solutions $\forall a,b \in G$ is redundant; Since is we have only that 
$$ax= b \quad \text{have solutions} \quad \forall a,b \in G,$$
then, when $b =a$, we have a right inverse $e$, and when $b= e$, we have an right inverse for $a$, which is arbitrary in $G$, hence by the proposition 1.3, $G$ is a group.

So, am I missing something in here, or is it just a pedagogical thing that is sometimes used to clarify the meaning of some statements ?

Comment: Can you clarify the sentence "when $a=a$, we have a right inverse $e$"?

Comment: The assumptions in 1.4 do not include the existence of an identity, and in 1.3 you have that the same identity works for every element and not just for a specific $a$. To apply 1.3 you need to prove the properties you need of $e$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path it was just a typo, see my edit please.

Comment: @MarkBennet Existence of the identity comes form the fact that $ax=b$ has a solution $\forall a,b \in G$. Note that $a,b$ are arbitrary, not some specific elements.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Having a left identity means $$\exists e,\forall a, ea=a$$ whereas what you obtain by specializing $[\forall a,b,\exists y,\,ya=b]$ to the case $b=a$ is $$\forall a,\exists x, xa=a$$ which is weaker because that $x$ depends, in principle, on $a$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Oh, you are right. Thanks for answer. I suggest you to turn your comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Counterexample:** Let multiplication in $G$ be defined so that $xy=y$ for all $x,y$. Then multiplication is associative, and for any $a,b$ the equation $ax=b$ has the unique solution $x=b$, but if $G$ has more than one element it's not a group.